# Weight Painting: Copy/Mirroring

Tags: weight-painting, mirror

First post and first time using Blender - Running 2.93 LTS

Had started working on my models head/face adding in weight paints to get it ready for use in another program. When I created the model I made sure that it was mirrored properly during the whole process and everything seemed fine, but I'm beginning to think that may not be the case.

I had worked on weights on one side of the face, clicked on copy vertex groups, and whether I mirror them vanilla or topology... It just doesn't seem to mirror over.

Without having to go through each point of the head and copying the individual weight amounts from one side to the other, is there another way to get the weights to mirror to the other side?

I have also [uploaded the model to my dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xqgwyqxuusz9i4k/Dave%20Facerig2.blend?dl=0) if anyone needs to see what the issue is. (BipLCheek_1-4, BipLCheekMiddle, and BipLCheekUpper)

Answer (score 2):

Weight mirroring needs some specifics in order to work correctly: vertex groups have to be named with an accepted suffix, a list can be found in the Blender manual, most commons are .L .R, .l .r, .left .right, .....

Then the mesh must have a correct topology, in order to pair left and right vertices (i.e. in your model it will be  impossible to mirror the hair, as they are randomly placed triangles).

Note also that there are two different kinds of weight mirroring: one is dedicated to central bones so that a weight applied on left side will be copied on the right side, another for non central bones (like limbs) in which if you paint on arm.l and a vertex group called arm.r exist, it will be painted too, according to topology corrispondence.

In your case I think it will be better go painting by hands, because if not you would have to rename all vertex groups, separate hair from the rest of the body, delete half of the model, add a mirror modifier, and still hope that uncorrect topology (like triangles and poles) don't interfere with mirroring functions, while hand painting needs only a little of practice and patience.

Comment: I was afraid of this, but kinda had a feeling it'd come to that. I'm honestly not too worried about the hair part. More just confused why it wasn't mirroring. I'm able to use X Mirror and whatever I paint appears on the opposite side perfectly fine. So I know the topology is technically "fine" for the head. However, when I mirror a vertex group that is part of the head, it just doesn't register and tosses errors. This also happens when I do rename the vertex groups too... It's just really strange.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use x axis mirroring in object settings <kbd>N</kbd> -> tool -> Options.  Or in the tool settings (right top corner of the screen)

Comment: I have used that while weightpainting, but doesn't really accomplish what I'm looking for unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the vertex groups to mirror by selecting all vertices in *Edit Mode*, then click on *Mesh > Snap to Symmetry*.

Then did a test of copying a vertex group, mirroring, renaming to the correct bone.